# How to use the "source" command to run commands simultaneously?

Tags: command-line

For example, I have an executable called `ex01` (C++ program).

And I have a text file that contains a set of invocations of this program with different arguments.

The text file looks like this:

```
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat  &
./ex01 command2 >> ex.dat &
./ex01 command3 >> ex.dat &
...
```

I can use the `source` command to do this task automatically.

But I was hoping to do this in parallel. How can I do that?

Comment: What makes you think that the `source` command has anything to do with parallelism?

Comment: I believe he is sourcing the file to run a bunch of commands. He wants to run the commands in parallel.

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive in your first sentence? I really don't get it. C++ source code doesn't really generate anything.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of sourcing the file, you should run it in a separate shell. The `source` command will run the script's contents in the current shell.

```
$ cat script.sh
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat;
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat;
...
$ sh script.sh
 ...
```

The semicolons are not necessary.

```
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat
...
```

To run the commands in parallel, add an ampersand (`&`) to the end of each command.

```
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat &
./ex01 command1 > ex.dat &
...
```

Note that the above will be problematic because two commands are writing to a single file. You should either write to different files,

```
./ex01 command1 > ex1.dat &
./ex01 command1 > ex2.dat &
...
```

or append to the file.

```
./ex01 command1 >> ex1.dat &
./ex01 command1 >> ex2.dat &
...
```

If your script repeats the same line over and over again, you can use a loop.

```
# Run 10 times
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
    ./ex01 command1 >> ex1.dat &
 done
```

---

**Edit:** If the argument's number changes linearly, you can use a loop like this:

```
# Run 10 times
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
    ./ex01 command$i >> ex.dat &
done
```

Comment: Thank you, You give me a lot of hints. Some part is modified by other guy who misunderstood my meaning. For each command line is different. I would like to do some work of bifurcation. But if for example 10,000 command is executed at the same time by command &. The computer is beyond the memory and cpu.